# Decimal point issue in displaying digits

Tags: android, kotlin, decimal, decimalformat, decimal-point

I have to display digit in two decimal points.

Let say value 0 should display as 0.00 and value 2.3 shoule display as 2.30.

To achive this I have done something like below :

```
Log.e(">>> percent ", ">> " + data.percent)
percent = String.format("%.2f", percent).toDouble()
Log.e(">>> percent ", ">> " + percent)
```

But the result you will notice is as below :

```
2021-04-15 11:55:54.580 10061-15047/com.dev E/>>> percent: >> 0
2021-04-15 11:55:54.580 10061-15047/com.dev E/>>> percent: >> 0.0
```

It should be 0.00 instead of 0.0

What might be the issue?
Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double` type does not have information about how to display.

So, do not use `toDouble()` method to the string.
Also, add `0` to the format string to denote the zero padding.

```kotlin
Log.e(">>> percent ", ">> " + data.percent)
val percentStr: String = String.format("%.02f", data.percent)
Log.e(">>> percent ", ">> " + percentStr)
```

Comment: same way if we want 1 decimal complusion, then we have to use %.01f or %1f ?

Comment: `%.1f` means *at most* one decimal digit, but the ending decimal zeros should be omitted. `%.01f` means *exactly* one decimal digit, and use the fact that like 1 is equal to 1.0.

Comment: I have changed it to "%.02f", still getting 0.0 instead of 0.00 ....

Comment: Did you remove `toDouble()` at the end and print the newly created String, not the original `percent`?

Comment: try like this:  percent = String.format("%.2f", percent.toDouble())

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

val df = DecimalFormat("0.00")

df.format(percent)

Answer (score 0):

**just change**

```
String.format("%.2f", percent).toDouble()
```

**to**

```
String.format("%.02f", data.percent)
```